# How does the Event Aggregator pattern manage its different publishers for its subscribers?

Tags: events, design-patterns, event-handling, eventaggregator

In an Event Aggregator pattern, the publishers publish events to the Aggregator and subscribers subscribe to a particular event via the Aggregator.

Suppose there are 3 subscribers, `SubscriberA`, `SubscriberB` and `SubscriberC`. They all want to subscribe to an event called `OnPowerUpEvent`. The `OnPowerUpEvent` can be fired by either `PowerItemA` or `PowerItemB`. There can also be *multiple instances* of `PowerItemA` and `PowerItemB`.

Based on this scenario, I don't understand how the Event Aggregator pattern would be able to allow the subscribers to subscribe to the event published by a specific publisher. It seems to me that the subscribers can only subscribe to the event `OnPowerUpEvent` in general, and respond to the event no matter who the publisher was.

For example, `SubscriberA` may want to subscribe to the event `OnPowerUpEvent` that is published by *any* `PowerItemA` instances. `SubscriberB` may want to subscribe to the event `OnPowerUpEvent` that is published by a *particular instance* of `PowerItemB`. And `SubscriberC` may want to subscribe to the event `OnPowerUpEvent` in general, *regardless* of who the publisher was.

In these 3 different cases, how does the Event Aggregator pattern manage this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Popular Event Aggregator implementations provides not only simple Publish/Subscribe features but more comples subscription filtering infrastructure, for instance Prism EventAggregator allows providing a predicate along with a handler: ([see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx))

```
FundAddedEvent fundAddedEvent = eventAggregator.GetEvent<FundAddedEvent>();

fundAddedEvent.Subscribe(FundAddedEventHandler, 
                         ThreadOption.UIThread, false,
                         fundOrder => fundOrder.CustomerId == _customerId);
```

Comment: For the `fundOrder` parameter in the lambda expression, what would the `fundAddedEvent` pass into it? From the MSDN, to publish an event, this is called: `EventAggregator.GetEvent<TickerSymbolSelectedEvent>().Publish(“STOCK0”);` It seems that the Event Aggregator wouldn't know who the publisher is, would it?